# .csproj properties page is not working VS4Mac 2022

Tags: macos, visual-studio, unit-testing, xunit

Hello All I have a MAUI Solution with a Tests.csproj included. I am using VS4Mac 17.6.4 (build 472), The project is XUnit. When I right click that csproj i get a context menu  with Properties on it.
When i click that item no properties are displayed.
All other CSPROJ in Solution will display Properties correctly
I wonder what could cause this page to NOT display:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.2.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="NSubstitute" Version="5.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="6.12.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Settings\" />
    <None Remove="Constants\" />
    <None Remove="ViewModels\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Settings\" />
    <Folder Include="Constants\" />
    <Folder Include="ViewModels\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DOMA\DOMA.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Properties page will not display for Any .csproj where

```
<UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
```